# golang send and receive objects

Tags: object, go, send

I am able to send and receive strings in golang using the following code:

```
//send side
message.Buf.WriteTo(conn)

//receive side
message, err := bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
fmt.Print("Message from client: ", string(message))
```

However, I would like to send the entire message object and receive it at the receive side

Something like:

```
//send side
message.WriteTo(conn)

//receive side
message,err :=bufio.NewReader(conn).ReadMessageObject()
```

I am new to Golang and any pointers are extremely helpful.

Comment: There are literally an infinite number of ways to "send objects". What encoding do you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll first want to declare a type for your messages. Something like:

```
type Message struct {
    From      string
    To        string
    Text      string
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
```

Then you'll need to decide how you want your new types to be encoded to/decoded from bytes, since all you can send through the wire are bytes.
You can for example send your messages as [json](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/), as [xml](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/), or as [gob](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/), etc. Which one you choose depends on what your requirements are, `json` is ubiquitous and readable but `gob` on the other hand is much faster, at least that's what I heard, haven't really used `gob` myself yet.

For example if you go with `json`.

```
// receive
var m Message
if _, err := json.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(&m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// send
if err := json.NewEncoder(conn).Encode(m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample. If I have multiple objects that I have to send on the wire? Any pointers on how to accomplish it?

Comment: You can use slices, maps, arrays.. it's up to you really, both `json` and `gob` can handle those just fine.

Comment: I checked out maps and slices and using both was able to send a set of objects. However, I would also like to be able to send stream of data continuously which seems to not work.

Comment: It would be better if you open a new question. One with precise explanation of what you're trying to achieve, with code you have so far, with what worked and what didn't, the desired result you would like to get and the undesired result you actually got.